# Movie analysis Xamarin , Android, iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need a solution because I don't know how to start doing this. I need to create a short video analysis. Exactly the possibility of drawing on this video. So while playing the movie, I can stop it and draw, for example, lines. This line overlaps the film. It is IMPORTANT that, for example, a line that will be superimposed on the 20 second and erased at the 25 second of the film and saved. It is after the video has been played that after analysis, this line will appear in 20 seconds and disappear 25 seconds. Often it will be a slow motion movie so it's important that the lines do not jump over time.

I am looking for a solution on Xamarina, but if it is active, I will try to rewrite it. Maybe there are some libraries?

Comment: Do you need to see the annotation only within your app or do also need to export the video and still have the annotations be present in this exported video outside your app?

Comment: the video will be sent between users. . And one of them can analyze the video

Comment: Between users, of your app only? Because if the video stays within your app, you do not need to modify the video file itself. You just need to have an overlay view above your video player which shows annotations at certain time. This also allows you to annotate the same video in different ways and save annotations separately without making copies of the video.

Comment: You can have a simple json / plist or a custom format for your annotations with timestamps and information required for displaying the annotation (similar to how subtitles work, but outside the video player).

Comment: User records a short video and sends it to the other user.  the second user make a video analysis and sends it back to the first user

Comment: You could use `Media Picker` to record a short video. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android Where do you send the video?

Comment: Sorry so late. Will I not have problems with delays etc. with slow motion?

Comment: For the large data, maybe there is dalays.